# Database queries with OR

Tags: django

I would like to implement a search box which returns all the results which are associated with at least one of the terms. In other words, a query with the terms separated by `OR`.

For instance:

```
Input: tomatoes potatoes watermelons
Query: tomatoes OR potatoes OR watermelons in db
Output: corresponding results
```

Preferably, but not necessarily, if a term is contained in all the results, it should be first or in the group of firsts.

I looked it up on Google but I could not modify an example that I [found](http://julienphalip.com/post/2825034077/adding-search-to-a-django-site-in-a-snap). If I replace the last row in `get_query` with `query = query | or_query`, I get an error in the template. I guess it is because of the lazy evaluation of the queries that Django performs, since the template works if I use verbatim the code in the link.

Comment: providing real code (sanitized as necessary) will help you get real answers.  There are at least 4 or 5 different things that you could be trying to do, and the answer to the question is dependent on which of them you're attempting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you're looking for [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).  Really though, you should try [django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/), if you're doing anything related to searching.